# What does "break" do in this ruby statement

Tags: ruby

This code snippet is from plataformecs gem simple_form, wiki section about "adding custom inputs":

```
out << template.image_tag(object.send(attribute_name).tap {|o| break o.send(version) if version}.send('url'))
```

The question is simply what does the code block after .tap {} mean? Specifically the initial "break" which looks strange to me.

Comment: it exits the block, no?

Comment: Look at @kajic's answer below which is short and correct.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`break argument` in a block causes the block to return `argument`. By default, `tap` returns the same object as it is given, but the break will instead cause it to return whatever `o.send(version) if version` evaluates to.

Comment: I think this was the the most concise answer to my question, and since we're talking Ruby, short answers should be rewarded.

Comment: Side-question: How would you do if you needed to `break` out of a `tap`, but wanted the original object to be returned?

Answer (score 4):

`#tap` is a method that basically "passes along" the block to the next.  It isn't supposed to "change" the flow of the method.  For example

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-tap

```
(1..10)                .tap {|x| puts "original: #{x.inspect}"}
  .to_a                .tap {|x| puts "array: #{x.inspect}"}
  .select {|x| x%2==0} .tap {|x| puts "evens: #{x.inspect}"}
  .map { |x| x*x }     .tap {|x| puts "squares: #{x.inspect}"}
```

It's sort of like a unix pipe, but has a chance to access the data as it goes along.  like a tap.

It is supposed to take something and return the same thing to the next part of the pipe.

However, using `break a` will **break out** of the tap, and **return a**.  That is, instead of returning what `#tap` would normally return (the same thing that it got), it would return `a` instead.

The use of `#tap` in this case is to pass values down the pipe "as normal", **except** when `version` is true; in that case it will send along `o.send(version)` instead.

Basically, the normal flow is

```
object.send(attribute_name).send('url')
```

and with `tap`, it's normally "unchanged".  However, using `break o.send(version)`, the flow is then instead

```
intermediate = object.send(attribute_name);
if version
  return intermediate.send(version).send('url');  # ignore the result of intermediate
                                                  # and replace it with o.send(version)
else
  return intermediate.send('url');                # maintain normal flow...it's like nothing
                                                  # was ever tapped
end
```

Comment: This is correct but I can't accept all answers so I chose @kajics but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

```
The break terminates a method with an associated block 
if called within the block.
```

So the meaning of the code is to change the value of `tap` on some condition:

- If version is true then `break` will bring to the next chain the result of `o.send(version)`.
- Otherwise it will bring just the incoming value of `tap`.